# Proof Verification: Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 1, Problem 1.

Tags: proof-verification

Problem: Prove if $ax = a$ for some number $a \neq 0$, then $x=1$.

Here is my proof: If $ax=a$, then $a^{-1}ax=a^{-1}a.$ By the existence of multiplicative inverses, $x=1$. Q.E.D

Now, I have a feeling that this doesn't show that $x$ HAS to be $1$. Is my proof complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in a division ring (such as a field), what you've done here is sufficient. It should be noted that the statement of the existence of multiplicative inverses should precede the introduction of $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful and state why $a^{-1}$ exists *before* introducing it into the proof. Carefully write out what $a^{-1}a$ means and equals, and deduce that $x = 1$ from the laws of arithmetic that Spivak gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're working with the real numbers. The reals form a field and so when you remove the zero, the multiplicative inverse exists for each element.  What you have done is valid.